# Android send an email in the background

Tags: android, email, smtp, gmail, jakarta-mail

I have seen many times the ease of sending an email in the foreground using the Android Intent Action.SEND.

However I need to implement a feedback form which emails us the details on completion. This doesnt really suit the Android Intent because the user wouldnt want to see the generated email before sending.

Does anyone have any sample code which can send an email form the background if we assume the smtp server is lol.does.thiswork and the username = lala, password = po.

Cheers

Comment: Did you put lol.does.thiswork and lala and po in there? Those are odd examples.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Sending Email in Android using JavaMail API without using the default/built-in app](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2020088/sending-email-in-android-using-javamail-api-without-using-the-default-built-in-a)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Possible duplicate of this: [Sending Email in Android using JavaMail API without using the default/built-in app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2020088/sending-email-in-android-using-javamail-api-without-using-the-default-android-app)  and plenty of example code in there.

as an editorial note, anytime an application I am using on a phone sends an email, I personally WOULD want it in the foreground.  If its just feedback from a form on your application, you could also use several solutions other than email: a web form in a webview, or create a socket back to a server you host, or a use a webservice etc...